# R grepl not catching all instances all instances of string

Tags: r, grepl

I have many very messy excel files with many different headers and in different locations. The below code is supposed to look for a match between a couple potential column header and tell me the row index. Sometimes they will have 2 (or more) rows of headers..Usually not different ones though.. I am not getting what I expected i.e. I expected rows 1 and 3 to be identified but are not..  Any ideas on what I can do? Thank you!

```
first<-c("im_adres_line1",  "im_adres_line2",   "im_adres_line3",   "im_adres_city",    "im_adres_state")

second<- c("1313 Mockingbyrd Lane", NA, NA, "Transylvania", "CA")
third<-c("Address 1", "Address2", "Address 3", "City", "State")

example_data<-data.frame(first, second, third)

matches <- apply(as.matrix(example_data), 1, function(x){ sum(grepl("adres|Address|im", x, ignore.case = TRUE, perl=T)) > 0 })

aind<-which(matches, arr.ind = TRUE) #finding row# with col headers
```

Comment: The column `first` has "adres" in each row, so `matches` is all `TRUE`. It's not clear from your description what logic you want the would result in only elements 1 and 3 being `TRUE`

Comment: I am really only interested in the row index.. I use that to set the header row..

Answer (score 1):

`grep` gives you the indices. `grepl` is the logical output.

```
apply(as.matrix(example_data), 1, function(x){ 
  grep("adres|Address|im", x, ignore.case = TRUE) })

[[1]]
[1] 1 3

[[2]]
[1] 1 3

[[3]]
[1] 1 3

[[4]]
[1] 1

[[5]]
[1] 1
```

This gives you the matching numbers. Keep in mind that it's the column number in the above case, which is probably irrelevant for this purpose.

```
names(table( unlist( apply( example_data, 1, function(x){ 
  grep("adres|Address|im", x, ignore.case = TRUE) }) ) ))

[1] "1" "3"
```

Comment: Thank you!! Is there an easy way to get 1 and 3 out of the results?

Comment: @tom See edit. It should be what you had in mind. In case you need numbers simply use `as.numeric` on top.

Comment: Thank you!! I really appreciate it!!